# How can I have multiple Firebase Database listeners and `exports.pushNotification` in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I have a listener that pushes notifications when a change happens in the Firebase Realtime Database.

```
exports.pushNotification = functions.database
    .ref("/Currency/Price")
    .onWrite((change, context) => { ... }
```

I tried just copying the same function shown above and just changing the database reference, but it just ended up disregarding the first one, so only the second database reference pushes notifications, and not the first.

How can I add another listener and push notification for another record in the Realtime database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to declare two different Cloud Functions that should be triggered on the same database location (i.e. node), just use another name, as follows:

```
exports.pushNotification1 = functions.database
    .ref("/Currency/Price")
    .onWrite((change, context) => { ... }

exports.pushNotification2 = functions.database
    .ref("/Currency/Price")
    .onWrite((change, context) => { ... }
```

---

If you want to declare another function but on another location, just do as follows:

```
exports.pushNotification1 = functions.database
    .ref("/Currency/Price")
    .onWrite((change, context) => { ... }

exports.pushNotification2 = functions.database
    .ref("/abcd/efgh")
    .onWrite((change, context) => { ... }
```